# android , push file via adb shell

Tags: android, shell, adb, recovery

Recently I formated my phone including internal storage. But since my phone doesn't have an external sdcard, I am having problems about copying rom file to my phone. When I try to push files through adb shell, I am stucked in "mount /data" step says that "Device or resource busy". İf I succes that step I am hoping to run "push rom.zip /sdcard/" succesfully. Any help please ?

```
c:\mini-sdk>adb shell
~ # ←[6nmount /data
mount /data
mount: mounting /dev/block/mmcblk0p12 on /data failed: Device or resource busy
~ # ←[6n
```

Comment: stackoverflow.com is primarily for programming questions. You should probably move this to http://android.stackexchange.com/ .